# Right syntax to get parameters values from html string chain

Tags: javascript

what is the correct syntax in this case to get parameters values for a function with two arguments.

At first my removeRow(id) function need only one parameter to do process.

**html code:**

```
"<a href=javascript:removeRow("+sport.id+"); class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>remove</a>"
```

**js code:**
// Remove row

```
function removeRow(sportId) {
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof sportId) {
        console.log(sportId);
    } else alert('Unknown id.');
}
```

Now, i want this function to take two parameters(**syntax???**)

**html code:**

```
"<a href=javascript:removeRow("+sport.id+","+ event.id+"); class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>remove</a>"
```

**js code:**

```
// Remove row
function removeRow(sportId,eventId) {
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof sportId) {
        console.log(sportId+ " " +  eventId);
    } else alert('Unknown id.');
}
```

Comment: href is not inside quotes.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the IDs and escape the quotes like this:

```
"<a href='javascript:removeRow(\""+sport.id+"\",\""+event.id+"\")' class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>remove</a>"
```

but I strongly recommend you do NOT use a javascript href and also that you use data attributes instead

```
'<a href="#" onclick="return removeRow(this)" data-sportid="'+sport.id+'" data-eventid="'+event.id+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">remove</a>'
```

and use

```
function removeRow(link) { 
  var sportId = link.getAttribute("data-sportid"), 
      eventId = link.getAttribute("data-eventid");
  if ( 'undefined' != typeof sportId) { 
    console.log(sportId+ " " + eventId); 
  } 
  else alert('Unknown id.'); 
  return false; // cancel the link
}
```

To do the same unobtrusively

```
window.onload=function() {
  var sportLinks = document.querySelectoraAll(".sport");
  for (var i=0;i<sportLinks.length;i++) {
    sportLinks[i].onclick=function removeRow(e) { 
      e.preventdefault(); // cancel link event
      var sportId = link.getAttribute("data-sportid"), 
          eventId = link.getAttribute("data-eventid");
      if ( 'undefined' != typeof sportId) { 
        console.log(sportId+ " " + eventId); 
      } 
      else alert('Unknown id.'); 
    }
  }
}
```

adding a class:

```
'<a href="#" data-sportid="'+sport.id+'" data-eventid="'+event.id+'" class="sport btn btn-xs btn-warning">remove</a>'
```